# Making SVG plots in R; why the need for X11?

Tags: linux, r, svg, plot, x11

I've been looking around for an answer for this. I seem to gather that some sort of X11 (or a virtual frame buffer) is always required for plotting.
 However I do not understand why that is needed for SVG graphics, seems like I should even be able to create them manually, so why does R seem to always need the X11?

I imagine that the X11 performs some functionality, like selecting colors from a palette or something like that. Is that the case? if not, how can I avoid the X11 completely.

I'm using ggplot2 to make a plot and gridSVG to extract it as in:

```
plot <- ggplot(data=data, aes(...)) + ...
print(plot)
mysvg <- grid.export()
```

Comment: you might be able to use the `Cairo` package to avoid this ... ?